# Honda Jazz Ignition Coil Issue

Tags: honda, ignition, jazz

I have Honda Jazz 2007, 200k KM mileage. My car ignition coil last maximum 6 months and after that it requires replacement. Whenever it happens, my car misfires only while driving. There are no any symptoms like rough idle, decrease in car power, poor fuel economy, difficulty starting the engine, check engine light, exhaust backfiring. Only car misfires while acceleration in driving. Even OBD device doesn’t show any error. I’ve replaced new plugs but still facing same issue. Whenever this happens, mechanic suggests me to change the whole coil pack because mechanic unable to find which coil is bad.
The only way for mechanic to find out, when car misfires on idle position. And this only happens when I don’t replace the coil and use my car for long time with bad coil (which is not practical). Please guide how can I fix this issue or at least a way to find out which coil is bad.

Comment: If your ignition coil pack is in one piece to serve all four cylinders, you're only choice is to replace the coil pack. However, if your Jazz uses four individual coils then you determine which coil is faulty by process of elimination. With engine idling and misfiring,  carefully disconnect one ignition coil. If the engine runs more erratically, that coil is fine. Reconnect and try another coil until the engine rpm doesn't change - that's the faulty coil.

Comment: @FDryer The OP said that it doesn't misfire at idle, only when accelerating while driving.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this model, but if there are spark plug wires between the coils and plugs, they could have excessive resistance and will cause the coils to "search" for another route "home", to ground, causing the coil to carbon track and destroy itself. Check the wire's resistance and replace as needed.